# Returning value to page of ajax error

Tags: jquery, ajax

My humblest apologies if this has been asked before. I've had a trawl through and can't seem to find what I am looking for.

I am serializing a form to send to a php page via ajax for inclusion into a database.

I have the success and error functions. When it was just success, it was returning everything to my error div (as I expected it would).

Like I say, I now have an error function and it is returning the error, but it isn't doing what I would like it to.

I would like it to be success - show in success div, error - show in error div. Right now, it is showing it in no div at all with no styling and it seems to be just doing whatever is in the success function.

I'm guessing I am missing something simple. Any help would be most appreciated.

The code I have is as below.

```
$("#insert").click(function()
{
    var formstuff = $('#person-data').serialize();
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'insert.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: formstuff,
            success: function(data)
                {
                    $('#error').hide();
                    $('#error').html('');
                    $('#success').append(data);
                    $('#success').fadeIn(1500);
                    $("#person-data")[0].reset();
                    $('#username').css('border', 'none');
                    $('#username').css('background-color', '#FFF');
                    $('#username').css('color', '#000');
                    $('#username').css('background-image', 'url(images/txtbox/id.png)');
                },
            error: function(data)
                {
                    $("#error").append(data);
                    $("#error").fadeIn(1500);
                }
        }
    );
    return false;   
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: As for the styling issues, could you post your HTML for `#success` and the other elements you are referencing in your success function? As for `it seems to be just doing whatever is in the success function` - the **success** function of AJAX doesn't mean the PHP script has executed as you expect, it simply refers to whether the **request** to that script succeeded (the error handler would be triggered if for example the target URL didn't exist)

Comment: @scrowler this is what is returned from the database when the record is entered (with the correct PHP formatting in the file of course): $firstname $lastname<br/>$address1<br/>[$email1]<br/>filed under $cat<br/>Was successfully entered into the database at $Time on $Date

I would like the errors returned (say when there is a duplicate entry) to the error div.

I understand what you mean - I guess any response from the PHP script is considered a successful response to ajax.

So, is there a way to differentiate PHP side at all so it goes in the right div?

Comment: the most simple way to distinguish PHP success/fail is to `echo 'success';` or `echo 'failed';` - but I normally echo a `json_encode`d result object, set `dataType: 'JSON'` in my AJAX call and look for that

Answer (score 1):

The `error` property of the jQuery [.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function actually takes a function with three parameters:

> Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )
>   A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error." As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests. This is an Ajax Event.

Your function only defines one parameter, `data`.  By doing so, you are trying to write the jqXHR object to your div.  You should write the `errorThrown` instead.

If you want to handle error messages through your error function, than your backend server code (in this case PHP) must set the HTTP status code to a value other than 200.  Your script must indicate that an error has occurred.  Maybe use the `500` status.  You can set the HTTP status in PHP using the [http-response-code](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php).

Comment: So, in my PHP script I have the following

if (!mysql_query($sqlp,$conn)) 
{
 die("Error: " . mysql_error().".");
 echo "Error: " . mysql_error().".";
}
else
{
 echo "$firstname $lastname<br/>";
}

Would I just put the HTTP status in the if (!mysql_query())?

See, I have 5 of these running as it is putting data into 5 different tables.

As you can tell, I am new-ish to ajax and jquery

Comment: Yes, you'd set the http-response-code in the if statement.  However, I do like @scrowler's solution better, which is to return JSON data indicating whether the inserts succeeded or failed.

Comment: I will have to have a look at @scrowlers solution. Little bits at a time. Don't want brain overload. LOL.

Thanks for your solution though